# Как использовать создание объекта через reflection класс?

Tags: php, ооп, yii2, рефлексия

Копался в коде `yii2` и наткнулся на метод `createObject` в котором объект создаётся через рефлекш класс методом `newInstance`. Зачем так делать? Почему не создавать через оператор new? Какие приемущества у такого способа? В каких случаях и для чего это использовать?

Answer (score 1):

Я не помню в каком контексте используется `ReflectionClass` в Yii2, но общая идея такая: механизм отражений (Reflection API) предоставляет довольно обширный функционал для получения сокрытой информации о внутреннем устройстве класса (в т.ч. и об их методах и свойствах), аналогичные вещи встречаются и в других языках программирования, например, в Java (откуда, насколько я понимаю, PHP в общем то и почерпнул эту идею). 
Создания экземпляра класса через `ReflectionClass::newInstance` может быть полезным, когда заранее не известно экземпляр какого именно класса мы будем создавать. В отличии от оператора `new`, в случае возникновения какой-либо ошибки `newInstance` выбросит исключение, которое мы сможем перехватить и обработать. Может быть полезным при создании различных фабрик и фабричных методов, а также DI контейнеров.

Не стоит искать какие либо преимущества у этого способа перед оператором `new`. Они предназначены для разных целей и, если вам необходимо просто создать новый объект, то это стоит делать через `new`. Также нужно помнить, что механизм отражений - довольно таки медленная штука. Местами даже очень медленная. Поэтому стоит его использовать только по делу и с полным пониманием зачем это делается. Стоит заметить, что многие вещи, которые многие решают через отражения можно сделать через замыкания и это будет быстрее (доступ к приватным и защищенным полям и методам класса, например; бывает очень полезным при написании юнит-тестов).

Приведу пример доступа к приватному полю класса через замыкания (PHP >= 5.4):

```
class SomeClass {

    private $somePrivateField = 'hello world';

    // ... тело класса
}

// клиентский код, например в юнит-тестах
$obj = new SomeClass();
$closure = function() {
    return $this->somePrivateField;
}
$privateFieldValue = $closure->bindTo($obj, $obj)->__invoke();
var_dump($privateFieldValue); // hello world
```